# Transform my simple code databinding one way to databinding two

Tags: android-databinding

I want to transform my code1 one databinding one way to code2 databinding two way is my code correct; i m not sur if i doing well thanks.

// code1

```xml
   ‹EditText android:text="@{user.name} " 
      android : afterTextChanged ="@{callback.change}"/ >
```

```java
   public void change (Editable s ) {
      final String text = s.toString(); 
      if (!text equals(name name.get()){
         name.set(text);
      }
   }
```

//Code2

```xml
   <EditText android:text="@={user.name} "
      android : afterTextChanged ="@={callback.change}"/ >
```

Answer (score 0):

just be careful field `name` in class `user` must be `ObserveableField<String>` or `MutableLiveData<String>` so you can remove text change listener and just add this:

```xml
<EditText android:text="@={user.name} "/>
```

now every change in `Edittext` will save in `name`